# Why does list(my_list) modify the object?

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

I happened on this peculiar behaviour accidentally:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a[:] = ['potato', a]
>>> print a
['potato', [...]]
>>> print list(a)
['potato', ['potato', [...]]]
```

By what mechanism does calling `list(a)` unroll one level of recursion in the string representation of itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list()` makes a shallow copy. The outer list is no longer the same object as the list it contains. It is printed as you would expect.

Answer (score 5):

The `...` is only displayed when an item contains itself -- that is, the same object.  `list(a)` makes a copy of the list, so the inner `a` isn't the same object.  It only shows the `...` when it gets to "a inside a", not "a inside `list(a)`".